# Prove that $ \lim_n \mathbb{E}(f_n(Y_n)) = p $.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, martingales

Suppose a function $f_n: \mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$. Holds $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(y_n) = p\,,$$ where $(y_n)$ is a real sequence such that $$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{y_n}{n}=1.$$

Now consider, a sequence of a random variable $Y_n$ such that $$\frac{Y_n}{n}\xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} 1, \ n\to\infty.$$ The function $f_n(Y_n) = \mathbb{P}(A\mid Y_n), \ n\geq 1$. I want to show that $\mathbb{P}(A)=p$. Here $A$ is any fixed event.

I proceed through the following way.
$$
\mathbb{E}(f_n(Y_n)) = \mathbb{P}(A)
$$

then we have to show that only,
$$
\lim_n \mathbb{E}(f_n(Y_n)) = p
$$

To show that I use Fatou's lemma and the property of $f_n$ that is given.

My question what is the use of the condition $\frac{Y_n}{n}\xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} 1, \ n\to\infty$? Or is there any other way to prove?

Comment: Try Scheffe's Lemma. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_lemma

Comment: @PeterMorfe yeah, but my question is different. What is the necessity of the requirements given over $Y_n$?

Comment: $f_{n}(Y_{n})$ is bounded so assuming $f_{n}(Y_{n}) \to p$ a.s., then $\mathbb{E}(f_{n}(Y_{n})) \to p$ as well by the dominated convergence theorem.